# How to remove white space in the middle of a pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is the example code I made to have a reproducible example.

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3
vals = np.array([[60., 32.], [37., 40.], [29., 10.]])

cmap = plt.get_cmap("tab20c")
outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3)*4)
inner_colors = cmap([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10])

ax.pie(vals.sum(axis=1), radius=3-0.9, colors=outer_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=0.9, edgecolor='w'),labels=["Europe","North America","Scandiavia"],
       pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=0.65)

ax.pie(vals.flatten(), radius=3, colors=inner_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=0.9, edgecolor='w'),labels=["Germany","France","USA","Mexico","Finland","Sweden"],
       pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=0.85)

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='')
plt.show()
```

which gives the following chart :

[image]

How can we play with the radius to reduce or even delete the white space in the middle ?

the goal is to have the following :

[image]

Comment: Set first ax.pie radius as 0.9, second ax.pie radius as 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out following code:

```
ax.pie(vals.sum(axis=1), radius=1, colors=outer_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=1, edgecolor='w'),labels=["Europe","North America","Scandiavia"],
       pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=0.65)

ax.pie(vals.flatten(), radius=2, colors=inner_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=1, edgecolor='w'),labels=["Germany","France","USA","Mexico","Finland","Sweden"],
       pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=0.85)
```

It gives me this output:
[image]